# What does 'return $next($request)' do in Laravel middleware?

Tags: laravel, closures, middleware

Please respect that I'm new to programming and Laravel, so this question might seem a little odd to the most of you.
But I think this is what stackoverflow is for, so:

When I created a new middleware with the command `php artisan make:middleware setLocale` there was already the `handle`-function with this code in it:

`return $next($request);`

and I'm wondering what exactly this line does.

Comment: persist / you are good you go / you have the right

Comment: @AhmedAboud and how? What does the Closure do in this context?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`$next($request)` just passes the request to next handler.
Suppose you added a middleware for checking age limit.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->age <= 18) {
        return redirect('home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

when age is less than 18 it will redirect to home but when the request passes the condition what should be done with the request? it will pass it to next handler.Probably to the register user method or any view.

Comment: took this as an answer since it gives an example and explanation

Answer (score 9):

This is explained in the documentation:

> To pass the request deeper into the application (allowing the middleware to "pass"), call the  $next callback with the $request.
>
> It's best to envision middleware as a series of "layers" HTTP requests must pass through before they hit your application. Each layer can examine the request and even reject it entirely.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#defining-middleware